# iOS sandbox test user account not working properly

Tags: ios, testing, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I'm trying to test my app's in-app purchases but when I try to log in as my sandbox tester it tries to send me to the settings screen to sign in there. however as I understand it, wouldn't that invalidate the tester.

Steps in order as I did them:
1: Create sandbox tester account on iTunes connect
2: sign out of itunes and app store as well as iCloud
3: opened the app and tried to purchase something. was prompted, telling me to sign into an account. 
4: Signed in using the test users credentials and still got redirected to the settings screen. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: There are a few discussions on the apple developer forums where people are reporting the same problem. Supposedly, apple is aware of the problem and they are working on fixing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to some people on the apple developer forums, regarding this particular issue, of course, you need only to verify the account and it seems to have done the trick for me.